# Who was the קדוש מרדוש?

Tags: rabbis, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, historical-figures, rishonim

Today, in a shiur, I heard someone quote an opinion of the *"קדוש מרדוש"* (pronounced "Kadosh Meradoosh", I think). The Bet Yosef in [E"HE 35](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14266&st=&pgnum=125) seems to quote the מרדכי who quotes him, so apparently he's a *rishon*. This is likely the same person who R' Akiva Eiger in Gittin (4th chapter) calls *מהר"י מרדוש*.

Who is the author of this work and when was it written? Is it an independant work or just someone whose *shitot* are quoted by others?

In what form was this work written (i.e. a perush on Talmud, an explanation on Mishnah, a sefer Halacha...)?

Comment: Don't know which tags apply and which dont. *Help please!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

His full name is R. Shlomo ben Avraham; [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20285&st=&pgnum=139)'s the entry for him in Otzar Hagedolim. מרדוש (should properly be מדרויש or some variant thereof; Maharshal, in his [teshuvah no. 29](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11884&st=&pgnum=107), where he brings the "chain of tradition" up to date to his own times, writes מדרוויש) is after the town where he lived - [Dreux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreux), France.

Maharshal lists him among the primary students of Ri (R. Yitzchak of Dampierre), who in turn was the successor of Rabbeinu Tam. So yes, he belongs to the era of Tosafos, as ShinTav suggested. As for the appellation הקדוש - indeed that suggests that he was killed al kiddush Hashem, but apparently nothing further is known about that.

Comment: Maybe in [the Children's Crusade of Stephan of Cloyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Crusade#Modern)? It was around that area around that time.

Answer (score 2):

'Kadosh' may imply that he was a martyr, in which case I would guess that he was killed in the crusades based on the time period.  This would in turn suggest that he was one of the Baalei HaTosafos, meaning his perush is most likely incorporated into Tosafos' gloss.  I know I recently saw Tosafos quote the 'Kadosh MiCorville' which would be a similar name with a similar meaning.